# An error occurs when calling stored procedure in mybatis

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I developing using spring-boot and mysql(8.0.15 for win64).
I wrote and executed processing to call stored procedure of mysql in mybatis(3.5.0), but
「Parameter number 3 is not an OUT parameter; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException」 is displayed and it does not work well.
Please let me know if there are any problems with how to write the program or how to use mybatis.

■stored procedure(mysql)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSP(IN id TEXT,IN name TEXT,OUT out0 INTEGER,OUT out1 INTEGER)
BEGIN
 SET out0 = 0;
 SET out1 = 0;
END;
```

■Result.java

```
public class Result{

private int out0;
private int out1;

public int getOut0(){
  return out0;
}

public void setOut0(int out0){
  this.out0 = out0;
}

public int getOut1(){
  return out1;
}

public void setOut1(int out1){
  this.out1 = out1;
}


}
```

■Dao

```
public interface testDao{

  public Result testSP(String id,String name);

}
```

■xml（sql query）

```
<?xml version>.....
<select id ="testSP" resultType="Result" statementType="CALLABLE">

{call testSP(
  #{id,mode=IN,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
  #{name,mode=IN,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
  #{out0,mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER},
  #{out1,mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER}
 )
}
</select>
....
```

■testcode

```
testDao testdao = new testDao();
System.out.println(testdao.testSP("testid","testname").getOut0());
System.out.println(testdao.testSP("testid","testname").getOut1());
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace incl SQLException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those OUT values are supposed to be set to the parameter object. See the [doc](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Parameters) for details.

So, you need to pass either a POJO or a `Map` to the mapper method.

```java
void testSP(Param param);
// or
void testSP(Map<String, Object> param);
```

If you use POJO, it must have all IN and OUT parameters.

```java
public class Param {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private int out0;
  private int out1;
  ...
```

Basically, you set the IN parameters before calling the method and MyBatis will set the OUT parameters.

```java
// POJO
Param param = new Param();
param.setId("testid");
param.setName("testname");
mapper.testSP(param);
assertEquals(1, param.getOut0());
assertEquals(2, param.getOut1());
// Map
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
param.put("id", "testid");
param.put("name", "testname");
mapper.testSP(param);
assertEquals(1, param.get("out0"));
assertEquals(2, param.get("out1"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for moving safely
I would like to ask you one more thing if the stored procedure function name contains an underscore:
I noticed that I got the same error message.
Does mybatis not recognize the underscore?
・testSP()  ⇒ OK
・test_SP() ⇒ NG（Even if I used POJO）

Comment: @H.Y `test_SP()` worked fine for me (mysqld 8.0.16 + Connector/J 8.0.16). As that error occurs even when there is no procedure with the specified name, you should double check the procedure definition.

Comment: Thank you very much! Work well!